# what are schema level changes has to be done from oracle 11g to 12c? any one have idea?

Tags: oracle11g, oracle12c, hp-ux

I am trying to install Oracle 12c on my HP-UX 11.31 Itanium machine ia64.

I am getting schema level error.

So anyone tells me what are all changes has to be done from Oracle 11g to Oracle 12c.

Already machine contains 11g related schema.

Comment: This isn't really a question about programming, so isn't strictly within the scope of StackOverflow.

Comment: What error? This is too broad a question to even speculate at.